# Alternative to jQuery .siblings()? .siblings is returning a set including current selected element

Tags: jquery

I have four div's which were cloned from another 4 div's. The cloned div's have new id's. When one of the new div's is selected and I do $(this).siblings(), I am getting back the 4 new div's instead of 3. I am not sure why this is happening and if cloning messed something up.

Is there a way to make siblings work right in my case? Is there a way to select the other 3 div's without using siblings()?

Comment: Can you please provide the HTML and jQuery snippets? Thank you

Comment: `$(this).siblings().not(this)`, maybe?

Comment: Are you sure you are selecting what you think you are selecting? According to the jQuery API: "The original element is not included among the siblings, which is important to remember when we wish to find all elements at a particular level of the DOM tree." Based on this, $(this).siblings() should ONLY return the siblings. If you post your markup, we may be able to help you better.

Comment: You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jatbv/

Comment: On that page, I get an alert of 2 -- not 3. Using Google Chrome.

Comment: yes I am sure. Maybe there's an issue in some certain circumstances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Rocket for giving me the idea for `not()`. However `not(this)` didn't work.

I had to `$(this).siblings().not('#' + $(this).attr("id"))`;